# React Native GiftedChat Message Ordering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I am using GiftedChat for RN and its working perfectly, but I can't manage proper message ordering by time if different devices have different time.

For example I have two devices that have manual time setup on them. At a specific time (let's say 12:00) the dates on the devices are: iOS - 12:00, Android: 12:03.

1. I would send a message from iOS to Android device at 12:01 (iOS Time) and it would show on Android at that time too (12:01, even though Android's time is 12:04).
2. Then, I would send a message back to iOS from Android at 12:04 (Android time) and it would show up in the right position on iOS. However, the time would be 12:04 on the message (iOS device time at that moment would be 12:01).
3. Last, if I send a message again from iOS at 12:02 (Android - 12:05) it would appear on Android above the last message (wrong order).

What should I do? I tried to fetch timestamps from the firebase server, but that would mean that they might not match with the actual time on the devices.

Something like `firebase.firestore.Timestamp.now().seconds` would not work either because it shows client time only.

Any ideas?

Basics of my implementation:

onSend():

```
db.collection(`${companyId.toString()}`)
    .doc("chats")
    .collection(`chats-${chatRoom.toString()}`)
    .add({
        _id,
        createdAt,
        text,
        user,
    });
```

onReceive():

```
snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
    _id: doc.data()._id,
    createdAt: doc.data().createdAt.toDate(),
    formattedDate: doc.data().formattedDate,
    text: doc.data().text,
    user: doc.data().user,
}))
```

Comment: Hi denistepp, I use `new Date().toISOString()` to store the timestamp for each message, and when i retrieve it them, it'd be something like `db.collection('chats').doc(chatId).collection('messages').orderBy('timestamp', 'desc').onSnapshot(...)`. With that said, I use my emulator and actual device to test, and gifted chat just sorts the messages according to my device/emulator time.

Comment: yeah but it won't fix the problem if devices times are different. I found the solution by calculating the offset over the only one origin of time source.

Comment: ahhhh i see... great to hear!!